# Strict semicolon syntactic semi-lateral symmetry

Tags: grammar, semicolons, question-mark

Is this ok?

> I’m in need of a punching bag; anyone want to volunteer?

Do both sides of the semicolon have to be the same syntax — that is, both questions or both statements?

And considering the latter half does not stand on its own as a statement, can I use it in a semicolon like this?

Comment: Second half *is* a sentence, but the **does** is implied.

Comment: Luke has also asked this at earlier at [Is this sentence proper?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123674/is-this-sentence-proper)

Comment: Note that OP has asked to delete the duplicate question & it currently has more close votes. Hence it appears that this one should be retained (subject to any *different* close reasons).

Comment: Unless you terminate the first half with a full and complete closure of thought using a period, the second half cannot originate. The question arises from a *previous statement* of thought. This is not a rule of grammar. Use a period, not a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

The Chicago Manual of Style says:

> In regular prose, a semicolon is most commonly used between two
>   independent clauses not joined by a conjunction to signal a closer
>   connection between them than a period would.

The key word is *independent*; neither clause has any syntactic influence on the other. (The definition of an independent clause is one that can stand on its own as a sentence.) The close connection between the two clauses simply has to be clear somehow.

[This article](http://www.scribophile.com/academy/correct-semicolon-usage) bemoans the much diminished use of the semicolon, and lists these rules for its use:

> Rule #1: Use a semicolon to replace a period.
>
> Rule #2: Use a semicolon as a super-comma.
>
> Rule #3: Use a semicolon before a conjunctive adverb.

The article concludes:

> To recap, a semicolon is used in place of a period when two clauses
>   are closely related; to separate a very complicated or long list; and
>   with a conjunctive adverb.

Comment: I feel like If neither clause has any syntactic influence on another than it seems that a sentence like "Did he just see me; I swore he saw me?" would be correct, but that seems way off to me.

Comment: Or something like "Did you want to go the store; did Jessica want to go to the store?"

Comment: Both examples sound like perfectly normal dialog to me.